# Let R be a relation on a set X. Then R is transitive if and only if, for any finite sequence x0, x1,..., xn of elements...

Tags: induction, equivalence-relations

Proposition: Let R be a relation on a set X. Then R is transitive if and only if, for any finite sequence x0, x1,..., xn of elements of X such that xi−1 R xi for all i ∈ [n], we have x0 R xn.

This is a proposition proved in my textbook. [image: Proof of Proposition]

I understand the (=>) direction by proving with induction. Can someone please explain the (<=) direction in more detail? I'm not sure what this proof is saying. I read it as p(2) = x_{1}Rx_{2) means x_{0}Rx_{2}. But how does this show R is transitive? Thanks!

Comment: Hint: write out what p(2) says (it's a statement about three elements $x_0$, $x_1$ and $x_2$: what does it say about them?).

Comment: [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020)'s a tutorial and reference for typesetting math on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I read it as p(2) = x_{1}Rx_{2) means x_{0}Rx_{2}. But how does this show R is transitive?

Not quite $p(2)$ is the condition that

> If $x_0 R x_1$ and $x_1 R x_2$ then $x_0 R x_2$.

Which is... the *exact* definition of transitivity.